# What if the same css & js files dynamically download many times?

Tags: javascript, css

There is a web page which dynamically download the `css & js` files.

```
<html> 
<head> <link rel="stylesheet" href="test1.css" type="text/css"/> </head>
<body>

 <input type="file" id="file1" />
 <input type="button" onclick="download();"/>

<script>  function download(){
    // if the selected file is css or js. this function download dynamically
 }
</script> </body> </html>
```

as you can see `test1.css` is attached in the page and already downloaded, unfortunately if any user select the same file `test1.css` and re-download via above fn().

does it affect on the page, if yes? then how should i avoid?

***Note : *** BTW i just tested the same and i did not see any changes or any affect on the page. but i am not sure at the large scale or at producation level.

Comment: What kind of affectation would you expect?

Comment: whether i am not sure but i have fear at `DOM` level action. do you think does it create any problem at DOM level

Comment: Can't know without the detail of download() function :)

Answer (score 2):

Including the same CSS file multiple times should not be a problem as long as there is only one file. More CSS files loaded in bad order might (most likely would) result in wrong rendering.

Including the same JS file multiple times should be avoided at all cost. You might encounter doubled event listeners, multiplied outputs and other bad stuff.

Just keep an array of files that have already been loaded. Then in the `download` function, you just check if the file has not been loaded with `loaded.indexOf(filename) === -1`

Comment: Thanks Jan, I was thinking the same to keep an array of files that have already been loaded